# check if a website is working error"The remote name could not be resolved"

Tags: c#

I'm trying to check if a website is online and taking urls from mssql server 2008 and if said website is not working, my code should send an e-mail.

It is working fine there is no problem with taking data from server but if I try to check a not working website for example `http://blabalabalabal.com` it gives me an error like: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
on this line:if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)

How can I solve this?

```
        string connectionString = "Data Source=eur-vpc\\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=Website";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        SiteeeID = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.SelectedValue);
        string url = "select http from AyrintiSite where SiteID='" + SiteeeID + "'";
        connection.Close();
        ArrayList Sites = new ArrayList();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(url, cn))
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cm.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Sites.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }

            }
        }
     for (int i = 0; i < Sites.Count; i++)
        {

            string url2 = Sites[i].ToString();
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url2));
          //  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
           // string gelenYanit = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            var response = GetResponse(request);
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                    mail.From = new MailAddress("blabla@gmail.com");
                    mail.To.Add("blabla2@yandex.com");
                    mail.Subject = "Website";
                    mail.Body += "Website is not working";
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("blabla@gmail.com", "******");
                    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                    MessageBox.Show("Mail send");

                }

        }
    }

    private HttpWebResponse GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException e)
        {
            if (e.Response == null)
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                mail.From = new MailAddress("blabla@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add("blabla2@yandex.com");
                mail.Subject = "Website";
                mail.Body += "Website is not working";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("blabla@gmail.com", "********");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                MessageBox.Show("Mail send");
            }
           return (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
        }
```

Comment: you should put a try catch around the GetResponse and handle the exception....blablabla can't be resolved by DNS so in this case the site not only isn't there, but the server doesn't even exist (or at least can't be resolved by DNS)

Comment: so you say i should change my DNS?

Comment: no, re-read. you should but a try-catch-block around the GetResponse line and handle the exception  -  I'm only guessing that, in your case since you use a web adress which does not exist, it will likely return some kind of DNS error (see answer from @Herdo - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31693942/129283)

Comment: @pastacool okey i edit my question can you check it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than returning an invalid status code directly, the `GetResponse` method likely throws an `System.Net.WebException`, whereas the `WebException` contains the actual error code/response. Therefore, wrap the `GetResponse` call in a try-catch block, or even wrap that in a method:

```
void YourMethod()
{
    string url2 = Sites[i].ToString();
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url2));
    HttpWebResponse response;
    string errorMessage;
    var gotResponse = TryGetResponse(request, out response, out errorMessage); // This is now a safe call
    if (!gotResponse || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        // Send mail and use errorMessage
    }
}

private static bool TryGetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, out HttpWebResponse response, out string errorMessage)
{
    errorMessage = null; 
    try
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        // Everything ok, if we get here
        return true;
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        if (e.Response == null)
        {
            response = null;

            if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure)
            {
                errorMessage = "Name resolution failed.";
            }

            return false;
        }

        response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this but now in catch it gives the same error

Comment: @fstkk Could you please add the exception details to your question then (exception type)?

Comment: System.Net.WebException {"The remote name could not be resolved: 'blabalabalabal.com"}

Comment: @fskk: yes, you still get an error because you use a non-existant web address. `http://blabalabalabal.com` does not exist so you get an error. handle it - you could probably return the error with the email you want to send out

Comment: @pastacool yes but it is my point. i have so many urls on my database and check all of them,some of them are not working for these i want to send e-mail.

Comment: @fstkk Which line of the `GetResponse` method above does throw the exception?

Comment: @fstkk: exactly, you should handle some/all exceptions you could get from  `GeResponse`and handle it which could mean you tell in your email what exactly the error was - in the case of blablabla you would tell in your email that the hostname cannot be resolved which in turn means there is no entry within the DNS to return an IP for blabla so there is no server to handle the webadress blabla......se my point?

Comment: @fstkk: have a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms346609(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @pastacool Indeed. However, all related errors would end up in a `WebException`, according to the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b2a9x7d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Any other exception would be caused by an "invalid" request.

Comment: @fstkk I tried it myself now with the URI you provided. Looks like the response is null. I rewrote the methods. Now you won't get the exception any more. Rather, the `TryGetResponse` method returns false, allowing you to use the `errorMessage` in your mail.

Comment: @Herdo okey now everything seems fine thank you so much. but can i ask you something? what if i want to add in my mail to which website is not working how can i do this?

Comment: @fstkk Just refer to `url2`? :) This is the website you're polling, so if `gotResponse` is false, `url2` couldn't be reached.

Comment: @Herdo haha yeah you are right,it worked. thank you so much :)))))